# Turn a for loop on an object into a .map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been told my function:

```
 for (const key of Object.keys(temp)) {
 this.sessionData.push(temp[key]);
 }
```

Must now use a .map instead,

I have tried this below:

```
Object.keys(temp).map(function(key) {
  this.sessionData[key];
})
```

But 1 I don't know if it's actually accurate, and also, it cant access the data outside of the scope of the function it is in, here is the whole function below:

```
public sessionData;

sessionDates(sessionsData) {
  const temp = {};
  this.sessionData = [];
  sessionsData.forEach(session => {
    const date = moment(session.startDatetime).format('DDMMYYYY');
    if (temp[date]) {
      temp[date].push(session);
    } else {
      temp[date] = [session];
    }
  });

Object.keys(temp).map(function(key) {
  this.sessionData[key];
})
```

TRYING TO USE THIS BELOW... session data is undefined, it can't access out of the scope?

```
    Object.keys(temp).map(function(key) {
  this.sessionData[key];
})
```

But this works..

```
 for (const key of Object.keys(temp)) {
 this.sessionData.push(temp[key]);
 }
```

So this new .map method can't access anything out of its scope.. sigh!

If anybody can help that would be amazing! Thanks!

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the map callback, and you aren't storing the result of the map into a variable for later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript all functions can access variables from outside (called "higher scope") - it's one of the strengths of the language and is called "capture".

The reason your code is failing is because it's using `this.sessionData` inside a `function` declaration, which cases problems because `this` in javascript is... somewhat complex. But you don't need it!

You also need to make sure you return the value you want to output. Here's how I would write it:

```
 this.sessionData = Object.keys(temp).map(key => temp[key]);
```

Comment: Any time. Good luck with your project!